# Image is not saved while creating a html file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a .NET application using twitter bootstrap.

I'm loading an image in .aspx page and saving that page as html file.

**Here is my code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string ISMfilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Download/");
        string FileNamePath = @D:"/Export.html";
        StreamWriter sWriter = File.CreateText(FileNamePath);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        pnlData.RenderControl(htw);
        sWriter.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
        sWriter.Close();
}
<asp:Panel  ID="pnlData"  runat="server" class="pnlData" style="background-   color:White;">
<img src="mountain.jpg" alt="" style="width:128px;height:128px"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

I'm able to create a html file but `mountain.jpg` is not getting loaded in html page. Image is not saved in html page.

Comment: You can't save a image into html page. You give link at load it from there. I think you migh wanna re-consider what you are doing.

Comment: How do you expect jpg-file to be saved inside plain html? As data-uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the image src as the filename, put a base64 string instead. This will embed the image to the html and give you what you're after.

E.g.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You can convert an image to a base64 string using various websites such as http://www.base64-image.de/

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme for more information.

FYI: Just remembered that IE8 only supports base64 strings as data URI's where the image is less than 32kb, it's the only browser with that issue that i've seen though.